# SQL Server 2016 RTM Download

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know when is SQL Server 2016 going to become available for download via MSDN? I thought it was today. As I type we still only have RC3 on there.

Comment: The announcement does say today, still early doors in the US though https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/05/02/get-ready-sql-server-2016-coming-on-june-1st/

Comment: Just for the information: Azure has vm template with sql server 2016 rtm installed on it. https://azure.microsoft.com/tr-tr/marketplace/partners/microsoft/sqlserver2016rtmstandardwindowsserver2012r2/

Comment: This is not a good Q and A for this site as it is highly time sensitive and the question will become instantly obsolete as soon as it appears.

Comment: Fair point Martin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2016 released on MSDN:

- [SQL Server 2016 Database engine & core features (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=650&Languages=en&PageSize=50&PageIndex=0)
- [SQL Server Management Studio 2016](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799832)
- [SQL Server Data Tools 2016 (June 2016)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The new download of sql 2016 management studio is an august release, you can find it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

When you download this installer, you can see Releaswe 16.3 in the set up. I came to this question because if you install the previous release of the management studio(the one in the accepted answer) you will get an error.

Latest update

[image]

Comment: That's the July release. There's no August release yet. Besides, that's not what this question was about

Comment: As you can see Panagiotis there is an August release of the management studio.

Comment: There is *now*. At the time this was posted it was a mis-labelled July update, accodring to the SSMS download page itself. If youy downloaded before August 12, you probably need to download the actual August update